# what would I have to do to get the new HTML Editor ajax control to work as a sharepoint content editor webpart?

Tags: html, sharepoint, editor, cross-platform

Microsoft have just released a few new ajax controls including an ajaxed up HTML editor control.

http://www.asp.net/learn/Ajax-Control-Toolkit/tutorial-50-cs.aspx

I would like to try this in Sharepoint (as the built in Sharepoint one is awful (no cross browser at all and flaky on IE) I tried the Telerik free one but it was not very stable.

I guess that getting the control up on a page won't be too hard, but how do I make sure the resulting HTML is stored in the Sharepoint way(tm)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to replace the standard SharePoint rich text editor, you would likely find it much easier to use jQuery than the ajax control toolkit. The MS ajax controls have a server component - you may be able to get it into a custom column type, but it's going to be a lot easier if you just replace the textbox with something better clientside.

The standard control works in a similar way - a standard textbox containing html is created on the server, and javascript is used to hide that and connect it to the rich text editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing you need to do to format the HTML for SharePoint.  If you are working with a field control you can expect that SharePoint will strip out a lot of the HTML from your control.